# Cannot get simple JQuery commands to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm having a ton of problems understanding Javascript and JQuery at the moment - they're causing me major headaches. Here's what I'm trying to do:

Replace the end of long item descriptions with ellipses. I want it to work for however many item descriptions that I have.

I tried doing it myself, completely failed, then tried to use a jquery.ellipsis plugin. Linking \jquery.ellipsis-master\jquery.ellipsis-master\src\jquery.ellipsis.js seems to have stopped my code from running at all. The alert does not show.

```
<p class="ideaText">Phasellus lacinia ... est.</p>
<p class="ideaText">Lalalalalala ... lalalala.</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="jquery.ellipsis.js" type="text/javascript">

                alert("JS works");

                $(document).ready(function () {

                    function pTruncate() {
                        $('.ideaText').each(function () {

                            $(this).ellipsis({visible: 3, more: '…', moreClass: 'more', separator: ' ', atFront: false});

                        });
                    };

                    pTruncate();

                    $(window).resize(function () {
                        pTruncate();
                    });

                });
```

Can somebody explain which file from Github I'm supposed to use? The ellipsis plugin is from https://github.com/bebraw/jquery.ellipsis

Comment: You should close that script tag sourcing the ellipsis plugins and open a new one for your code (in which you can omit the `src` part)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put your JS code in a `<script>` element that has a `src` attribute. It's one or the other. To do what you need you have to add your own `<script />` tag, like this:

```
<p class="ideaText">Phasellus lacinia ... est.</p>
<p class="ideaText">Lalalalalala ... lalalala.</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="jquery.ellipsis.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    alert("JS works");

    $(document).ready(function () {
        function pTruncate() {
            $('.ideaText').each(function () {
                $(this).ellipsis({
                    visible: 3, 
                    more: '…', 
                    moreClass: 'more', 
                    separator: ' ', 
                    atFront: false
                });
            });
        };

        pTruncate();

        $(window).resize(function () {
            pTruncate();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's the syntax for all the different coding languages that are really holding me back, I'm slowly getting to grips with what's acceptable and what's not...

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I'm sure you'll get there :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your script inside a `<script></script>` tag if it's in your html. This is basically telling the browser that anything between these tags is JS. The external link to a script is used to define a link to an external JS file. You can check out this detailed article that explains how exactly JS is embedded http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch12_02.htm

It will work if you do this

```
<p class="ideaText">Phasellus lacinia ... est.</p>
<p class="ideaText">Lalalalalala ... lalalala.</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="jquery.ellipsis.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
  alert("JS works");
  $(document).ready(function () {
             function pTruncate() {
                 $('.ideaText').each(function () {
                 $(this).ellipsis({visible: 3, more: '…', moreClass: 'more', separator: ' ', atFront: false});
                        });
                    };

              pTruncate();
              $(window).resize(function () {
                        pTruncate();
                   });

              });
</script>
```

Cheers and happy coding!